# JDBC SQL Server connection error in JSP Project

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server.

While connecting to server from the code, it is giving me an error :

`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect`.

The code is given below :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>


<%
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection cn = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MSI;DatabaseName=LeadManagement;user=sa;password=123456");

    Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from userDetail");
%>
```

**Screenshot - SQL Server connection instance**

[image]

Why I'm getting this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated code snippet :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>


<%
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://MSI;databaseName=LeadManagement;user=sa;password=123456;";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);   
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from userDetail");
%>
```

Note: Download the Microsoft JDBC Driver jar from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15).

Another point to be noted - Please verify the url. It must follow this syntax - `jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>`